# How to add additional informations in NSFetchedResultsController's section

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

I have a custom section in `UITableView`, it has an `UIImageView` and a `UILabel`. Using `NSFetchedResultsController` can i have set image based on section model. Let say section model has `imageName` and `sectionTitle`. Based on current implementation i got `<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>` as a section Object. Is this possible to get by custom object in section's object.

Thanks

Comment: Please explain it more . and what is "section model"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I know what you mean. You created a NSFetchedResultsController object passing a certain entity as an argument for sectionNameKey. So your custom section is based on this entity. This is what you mean by 'section model', I guess.

If you want to access the objects in the section, you can use the following code:

```
//create array for demonstration purposes
var exampleArray = [[YourEntityType]]()

for sectionInfo in fetchedResultsController.sections! {

//this will give you an array with all the objects in the section            
let objectsForSection = sectionInfo.objects as! [YourEntityType]

//this will add the array above to another array, so you will have access to all the objects of all the sections      
exampleArray.append(objectsForSection)   
}
```

You can also use keyValue coding, like this:

```
//create sectionInfo variable, where 2 is the number of the section (the third section in this example
let sectionInfo = fetchedResultsController.sections![2]

//access the needed entity object from the sectionInfo
let exampleVariable = (sectionInfo.objects as! AnyObject).valueForKeyPath("yourEntity") as! YourEntityType

//access the needed attribute object from the sectionInfo
let anotherExampleVariable = (sectionInfo.objects as! AnyObject).valueForKeyPath("yourEntity.yourAttribute") as! YourAttributeType
```

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for, Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Once you know the object associated with the section, you can figure out which image and label text to display.

Make sure your object (presumably a relationship to the main entity fetched by the fetched results controller) provides the necessary information.